# vector elements unexpected behaviour after applied `std::transform()` function

Tags: c++, vector

After applied the `std::transform()` to `array` and `vector` respectively. The `array` code works as expected, however, the `vector` code doesn't `cout` its elements after the use of `transform()`:

```
int increment(int x)
{
  return (x + 1);
}


int main()
{
  std::array<int, 2> arr1{1, 2};
  std::array<int, 2> arr2{};
  for (const auto &item : arr1)
    std::cout << "arr1: " << item << '\n';

  std::transform(arr1.begin(), arr1.end(), arr2.begin(), increment);

  for (const auto &item : arr1)
    std::cout << "arr1: " << item << '\n';

  for (const auto &item : arr2)
    std::cout << "arr2: " << item << '\n';

  std::vector<int> vec1{1, 2};
  std::vector<int> vec2{};

  for (const auto &item : vec1)
    std::cout << "vec1: " << item << '\n';

  std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), increment);

  for (const auto &item : vec1)
    std::cout << "vec1: " << item << '\n';

  for (const auto &item : vec2)
    std::cout << "vec2: " << item << '\n';

  return 0;
}
>>
arr1: 1
arr1: 2
arr1: 1
arr1: 2
arr2: 2
arr2: 3
vec1: 1
vec1: 2

Process finished with exit code 139 (interrupted by signal 11: SIGSEGV)
```

Items were missing after applied by `transform()`. It is run by CLion with c++20.

Comment: You probably want `std::back_inserter`.

Comment: `std::array<int, 2> arr2{}`, `arr2.size()` is 2, `std::vector<int> vec2{};`, `vec2.size()` is 0.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `vec2` is *empty*. You try to modify elements in this empty vector which will lead to *undefined behavior*.

The simple solution is to make sure that the vector is of the correct size to begin with:

```
std::vector<int> vec2(vec1.size());
```

You could also use [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter) to dynamically append to the vector:

```
std::transform(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), std::back_inserter(vec2), increment);
```